# В чём отличие между выводом f и *&f в функции, принимающей ссылку?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, ссылки

```
void foo(int& f){
   cout << f << endl;
}
void foo1(int& f){
   cout << *&f << endl;
}
```

Есть ли в этих записях различия? Выводят они одно и то же значение. Но может различие где-то глубже? А также в таком случае:

```
void foo(int*& f){/* ... */}
void foo1(int& f){/* ... */}
```

Записи будут эквивалентными, не учитывая, что придётся разыменовывать f, чтобы получить значение? Что использовать лучше? Я так понял, вторую функцию лучше использовать, если мы передаём переменные, а первую, когда работаем с массивом. Поправьте, если не прав.

Comment: В таком примере запись `*&f` бессмысленна. Можно навешать еще парных взятий адресов и разыменований, но зачем?

Comment: Можете привести пример, когда такой синтаксис имеет смысл? И имеет ли вообще?

Comment: Можно придумать искусственный пример, когда перегружены операторы `&` и `*`, а вот что-то реалистичное - это я затрудняюсь...

Comment: Во втором пункте, записи совсем не эквивалентны. `int x; foo1(&x);` скомпилируется, а `foo(&x)` - нет (чтобы `foo` работал, адрес придется сначала записать в переменную).

Comment: "вторую функцию лучше использовать, если мы передаём переменные, а первую, когда работаем с массивом"? Не ясно, что имеется в виду. Приведите пример. `int a[10]; foo(a);` - это даже не скомпилируется. О какой "работе с массивом" идет речь?

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о ссылке на фундаментальный тип, такой как `int &f`, то никакой разницы между `f` и `*&f` нет. Разницы нет не только с точки зрения наблюдаемого значения, но и с точки зрения наблюдаемого *объекта*. Но если заменить тип `int` на класс-тип, то благодаря перегрузке операторов разница может быть сколь угодно большой. Из вашего вопроса не понятно, связан ли он именно с типом `int` или нет.

О какой "эквивалентности" вы спрашиваете во втором случае - не ясно, ибо параметры функции ссылаются на совершенно разные сущности. Никакой логики в утверждении "вторую функцию лучше использовать, если мы передаём переменные, а первую, когда работаем с массивом" я не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo(int*& f)
```

тут аргументом является неконстантная ссылька на указатель, поэтому вы можете выполнить действия над указателем в теле функции, и тогда изменения произойдут с тем указателем, которую вы передадите:

```
{     
    ++f; 
}
```

Но передавать в функцию имя массива вы не сможете, поскольку имя массива связана с определенным количеством элементов, и потому может рассматриваться как константная ссылька. Т.е. в следующую функцию:

```
void foo1(int* const& f)
{ cout << *(f + 1) << " : " << *f << endl; }
```

вы можете передать имя массива. Тип аргумента не разрешает выполнить действия с самым указателем, а (f + 1) это уже другой указатель.

В следующую функцию:

```
void foo2(int* f){ ++f;  }
```

вы можете передать и имя массива и любой  указатель, поскольку аргумент это другой указатель,  инициализированный тем же адресом.(происходит копирование)

И, наконец:

```
void foo3(int& f) { ++f;  }
```

Имеет аргумент_ссыльку на обьект. Т.е. в функцию моожно передавать обьект, и все изменения произойдут именно с этим обьектом. В данном случаи инкрементируется значение обьекта.

Для того, чтобы лучше понять все это, напишите для себя тестовую программу. Например:

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30};
int *m = a;

foo2(m);
cout << *m << " ... " << *a << endl;

foo1(a);
cout << *m << " ... " << *a << endl;

foo(m);     
foo(a) // error

foo2(a);
cout << *m << " ... " << *a << endl;

foo3(a[1]);
cout << *m << " ... " << *a << endl;
```